Why did Anthony Goater move from Hampshire to Somerset before May 1810
My ancestor married in a small village south of Bath on 11 May 1810.  His wife was Sarah Higgins. They were married at St Peters (Englishcombe).  I've always puzzled over his reasons for moving from Hampshire to Somerset.
Anthony Goater (1773-1846) born in Hampshire.  I think there were three generations of Anthony Goater.
Sarah Higgins (1777-1861); she may have been married before as there is reference to the name Sarah Hawkins Higgins.
Why did Anthony move and did he travel as one journey or a journey made in several stages?
There are records of three children; Martha (baptised 13 Feb 1814), Elizabeth (baptised 26 Jan 1817), Mary (baptised 12 Jan 1823).  All are recorded at St Michaels (Twerton).  On Mary's record Anthony is recorded as a Coal Merchant.  Twerton is very close to Englishcombe where Anthony and Sarah married.
I have an additional question relating to Anthony Goater.  I now find that he spent the last 12 years of life paralysed.  So any details about living a sedentary life (in the mid 1800s) would be of interest.

Have you found baptisms for his children?  That would be useful to [edit] into your question. They should mention a date and location and may also mention his occupation. Where was he and what was his occupation for the 1841 Census?

Do you have no theory of your own as to 'why'?

No theories as yet.

You haven’t given us much information to go on here.
People moved around the country for all sorts of reasons, often related to their employment but many other reasons could have applied. The distances in this case are not great. Southampton to Bath is 66 miles. Northern Hampshire is even closer. So he didn’t go very far.
What work did Anthony do? (If you don’t know, it should be on his death certificate). Was he in the army and posted to Bath? Was he a stonemason, whose work often meant travelling? Was he a navvy or labourer building canals? And so on.
Where was his wife born? Did she come from Somerset? So did they meet there, or just marry there?

His death certificate indicates he had been a labourer, but he had been paralyzed for 12 years.  I am assuming he was a farm labourer - given the village setting where he lived.
